# Creating pointers out of HashMap objects in an object array

Tags: java, arrays, object, pointers, hashmap

This is sort of an follow up to the first post I made, lets say I got two classes:

```
public class Carinfo {

    private String carname;
    //The Carinfo[] value is set when making a new car
    //so for the object ford the array holds 3 null pointers
    private Carinfo [] value; 

    Carinfo (String someCar, int carValue) {
        this.carname = someCar;
        this.value = new Carinfo[carValue];
    }
}
```

And the second class:

```
public class CarPark {

    HashMap<String, Carinfo> carGarage;

    CarPark() {
        carGarage = new HashMap<String, CarInfo>();

        Carinfo ford = new Carinfo("Ford", 3);
        Carinfo audi = new Carinfo("Audi", 2);

        carGarage.put("Ford", ford);
        carGarage.put("Audi", audi);
    }
}
```

So let's say for whatever reason I want the object ford who has 3 null pointers 
in its Carinfo array, to point at the object audi.
Meaning I can go through the Carinfo objects and list the pointers each car 
has to other cars.

Think of it as a family, I want to see what cars are related to each other.
I am having a hard time creating a method that will point to other objects 
in my Carinfo HashMap.

Any "pointers"? If anything is unclear please let me rephrase or try to explain it better.

Cheers

Comment: What are you really trying to accomplish here? Are you learning Java?

Answer (score 1):

I don't really understand what you're trying to do. One way to realize that is to provide a specific method to add a relation. For example, with your array you could do that:

```
public class CarInfo {
  private Carinfo[] value;
  public void addCarInfo(CarInfo carInfo, int position) {
    value[position] = carInfo;
  }
}
```

Anyway, it is not a good idea to have an array, you should use a List.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend *not* storing the relationships between cars inside the `Carinfo` objects themselves.  Instead, you should use a general-purpose graph library (or write your own general-purpose graph library).

As you probably know, a [graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_%28mathematics%29) is a set of nodes and edges, and each edge represents a relationship between two nodes.  The notion that your current code describes is really just a directed graph: each car is a node, and each car can hold some number of references to the other cars, where each reference represents an edge pointing out from that car.

Graphs are such a common abstraction in math and computer science that plenty of libraries have been implemented to represent graphs, with the side benefit that several popular problems are solved for any code that uses the libraries (for instance, finding a multistep relationship between two cars using the fewest number of edges, or finding the smallest number of edges needed in the graph to ensure that all the cars are still indirectly connected).  I would recommend searching for already-implemented graph libraries, and then using the one with the best features for your overall problem.  If this is a homework assignment, though, you should probably implement your own graph library.  This isn't too hard: you need to store nodes and edges somehow (you can just keep a list of nodes, and you could use an edge list or adjacency matrix to store edges), and you will need to provide the algorithms you care about in a somewhat more general form.  This may seem like more work, but the benefits of making your code more modular will pay off quickly.  You'll create fewer bugs in the first place, since each part of your code performs only one job, and you'll be able to fix bugs more easily and quickly, probably saving you time overall.

Answer (score 0):

For starters you'll need accessing methods on your `CarInfo` object in order to play with the value array you've set up.

```
public CarInfo[] getCarValue() {
  return value;
}
```

Now, when you're playing in a method you can call it as follows:

```
CarInfo[] fordValueArray = carGarage.get("Ford").getCarValue();
```

This array now points to the one you created on the 3rd command of `CarPark()`.

With that we can do:

```
fordValueArray[0] = audi;
```

---

Now, that all said, it seems a little unclear why you'd set up a class relation like this. The naming of `value` is seemingly non-intuitive because *at face value* what you've asked is how we can have a car's value relate to a number of other cars independantly. Ford's first value is an Audi? What are the other two values? Why would we be limited to 3 at all?

Comment: Hi, sorry for the poor choice of variable names. The reason why it is set up as it is, is that its one of my assignments at Uni. So I really have to go with whatever I'm given in terms of class setup. It would perhaps have been more intuitive if I had set it up as a relations network. So for that I am sorry, trying out your solution right after dinner. Thanks